# BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray rotates image taken with camera

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, imageview

I am using PictureCallback's `onPictureTaken` to capture an image and show it in an ImageView. Here is my code.

```
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
  mCameraData = data;
  ...
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(mCameraData, 0, mCameraData.length);
  mCameraImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

The problem is that while the image looks good in my SurfaceView, it is rotated 90 degrees in the ImageView. Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Comment: @CommonsWare, how do I get exif from byte array or bitmap? I don't know the path from `onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)`. So I cannot use `ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(file path);`

Comment: Either write it out to a file, or use another EXIF parser. For example, in my CWAC-Camera library, I use an EXIF parser pulled from the MMS client from the Android Open Source Project: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/tree/master/camera/src/com/android/mms/exif